# Type inference in Elm

Tags: types, type-inference, elm

I just began learning Elm and I got stuck with type annotation issue.

This code works:

```
viewInput : String -> Html msg
viewInput myText =
    div [ style [("color","red")] ] [ text myText ]
```

This one raises a compiler exception:

```
viewInput : String -> Html msg
viewInput myText =
    input [ type' "text", placeholder myText ]
```

The error is

```
-- TYPE MISMATCH ------------------------------------------------------ form.elm

The type annotation for `viewInput` does not match its definition.

62| viewInput : String -> Html msg
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
The type annotation is saying:

    String -> Html a

But I am inferring that the definition has this type:

    String -> List (Html a) -> Html a

Detected errors in 1 module.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are just missing some brackets at the end...

Your code should be

```
viewInput : String -> Html msg
viewInput myText =
    input [ type' "text", placeholder myText ] []
```

This is because the `input` function, as `div` does, wants in input two lists, one for the attributes, one for the other `Html` pieces it contains

Comment: indeed it works, thanks! I'm digging into the docs but can't find the precise reason why I need the square brackets.

Comment: @pietro909 just edited the answer with an explanation

Comment: thanks! really good explanation. Need to wait some minutes to accept you answer.

Comment: btw ciao @pietro909, sono Marco, ci siamo conosciuti al Codemotion

Comment: Grande! lieto di incontrarti di nuovo! Elm is amazing, I should have tried it before :-)